# why some php if conditions are written like if(1>2)

Tags: php, if-statement, case

I have seen in some of the old php programs, if conditions are written like below

```
if(1>2){
 //something went here..
}
```

what is the use of these conditions, these type of if conditions will never be true. Please explain

Thanks
Sricharan

Comment: equivalent to `if(false)` which is a bad testing habit

Comment: sort of like a goofy way to do a block comment I suppose.

Comment: I'm going to say it's for the rare case that the mathematicians decide that it should go 2,1,3,4,5 , therefore it can alert the programmer to start panicing.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript a brutal reminder that my codes are all open to matematical inconsistencies attack, better known as MIA (ex: "mama mia!").. all those checks i should add!! :D (NOTE: yes, this is ironical, don't write those checks)

Comment: I'll start writing the CVE

Comment: It is a comment but the IDE beautify the code inside it.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that it's their version of commenting out code, setting the if-statement to a static expression that can never run and coming back to it at a later date to either start using it again or continue working on it.